# How to input a user entered string into an HTML <input /> (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to develop an app for my school's grade portal (Using the Home Access Center platform).

(Im a bit of a beginner so please excuse any lapses in the information I have provided and if you need to me to provide it, I will be active)

So far I've been able to send the request and receive a response in the form of a string through .responseString, and when I print the response I'm getting an HTML doc type with the login parameters near the bottom. I have gotten this far, but I'm not sure how to pass my user-inputted data to the correct location. (I know where the parameters are located, but don't know how to access them).

The HTML file output looks like this,

```
<div>

   <label class="sg-logon-left" for="LogOnDetails_UserName">User Name:</label> 

   <input class="sg-logon-right" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User Name: field is required." id="LogOnDetails_UserName" name="LogOnDetails.UserName" type="text" value="" /> 

   <span class="field-validation-valid sg-logon-validation" data-valmsg-for="LogOnDetails.UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

</div>
```

(just a small chunk of the file)

I've tried passing multiple different combinations of the parameters using a dictionary, but none of them have actually made it to that location. This website uses a action form (I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure about different interactions with HTML elements), but this is what passes when I run my program

```
<form action="/HomeAccess/SessionReset?ReturnUrl=%2FHomeAccess%2FAccount%2FLogOn%3FReturnUrl%3D%252fhomeaccess%252f" method="post">    
< div class="sg-container" id="SignInSectionContainer">
```

I will send my current Swift code if need be, but if you might have a solution, the website is https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f and I'm using Alamofire and Xcode (latest versions)

I have looked extensively for a thread that might have my answer, but I'm unable to find anything besides information on how to parse HTML files.
Thanks a ton for any help and please reroute me if this is a duplicate question.

Swift Code
    @IBAction func getLoginData(_ sender: Any) {

```
    let username = Username.text!

    let password = Password.text!

    if (username != "" && password != "")
    {
        let params : [String : String] = ["name" : "LogOnDetails.UserName","type" : "text", "value" : username]


        //Make database a choosable number parameter later
        sendLoginRequest(url: HAC_URL, parameters: params)
    }
    else
    {

        errorOutput.text = "Invalid Login"
    }

}


func sendLoginRequest(url: String, parameters : [String : String])
{
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding()).responseString
    {
        response in

        if response.result.isSuccess
        {

            self.errorOutput.text = "Success"
            print(response.result.value!)

        }

        else if response.result.isFailure
        {
            self.errorOutput.text = "Connection Issues"
            print(response.error.debugDescription)
        }

        else
        {
            self.errorOutput.text = "Program Failure"

        }

    }

}
```

**Edit**
I need to input a user entered string into an HTML

Comment: Please put your current code that you are trying with swift, just like you have writen HTML, so we can help you. Plus see on stackoverflow how to ask a good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alright I included the Swift code, and changed the question a bit

Comment: Your list of parameters doesn't look right. As far as I can tell Alamofire request parameters are just name value pairs, you don't need type or text, just the value. You also haven't actually attempted to send the password. Try ["LogOnDetails.UserName":username, "LogOnDetails.Password":password]

Comment: I tried that and am running into the same issue. I'm also suspecting that I need to set up something that triggers the button on the site.